# Hive JDBC connection issues with Kerberos authentication - R

Tags: r, jdbc, hive, kerberos, rjdbc

I am trying to connect Hive via JDBC using RJDBC package in R. Hive is configured with Kerberos authentication. i am using CDH 5.6.0. Hive version is 1.1.0. i am using following JARS

```
hive-jdbc-1.1.0-cdh5.6.0-standalone
hadoop-common-2.6.0-cdh5.6.0
```

my code was

`library(RJDBC)
drv <- JDBC("com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver",list.files("Jars/",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))`
`url.dbc =  paste0("jdbc:hive2://xx.xx.xx.xx:10000/default;principal=hive/xx.xx.xx.xx@XXX.COM");
conn=dbConnect(drv,url.dbc,"username","password")`

while executing this code i am getting following error,

`Error in .jcall(drv@jdrv, "Ljava/sql/Connection;", "connect", as.character(url)[1],  : 
  java.sql.SQLException: [Cloudera][HiveJDBCDriver](500164) Error initialized or created transport for authentication: Peer indicated failure: Unsupported mechanism type PLAIN.`

i am struck up here long time, Kindly help me on this error

Comment: May I know which version of JDBC driver you are using .. I have a Kerberos enabled cluster where I was able to create connection. But Funny fact is that I'm getting same error in Impala.

Comment: with updated drivers Impala is also working.

Answer (score 4):

I have access to a Kerberos enabled cluster at my workplace. I am able to connect using following code..

**Step 1** : Download latest JDBC driver from [Cloudera](https://www.cloudera.com/downloads/connectors/hive/jdbc/2-5-18.html). I used 2.5.18 in Redhat 6 (x64)

**Step 2** : Unzip and use only JDBC 4 connector API.

**Step 3** : issue command `klist` in terminal [I hope you are using linux, if not you may have to setup active directory] and see that there is a ticket active. If the ticket is not present generate it [possibly with the help of admin]

**Step 4** : Once you have active ticket [see it as described in Step 3] place all jars unzipped in Step 2 in a folder. [here in my case it is in `Drivers/Cloudera-Simba/JDBC4/` inside my R-project directory]

**Step 5** : One important thing is that if you have **Sentry** governing Cloudera Cluster, make sure to login and run following R code from that user who have desired access level.

**Step 6** : Run following R code with appropriate host name etc configured in the JDBC Url.

```
drvH <- JDBC(driverClass = "com.cloudera.hive.jdbc4.HS2Driver", 
             classPath = normalizePath(list.files("Drivers/Cloudera-Simba/JDBC4/", pattern = ".jar$", full.names = T, recursive = T)), 
             identifier.quote="`")

connH <- dbConnect(drvH, "jdbc:hive2://master.rbi.org.in:10000;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=YOUR_REALM.COM;KrbHostFQDN=master.rbi.org.in;KrbServiceName=hive")

# test it
dbGetQuery(connH, "show databases")
```

Hope this helps.

You can find more information about Kerberos configuration [here](http://www.simba.com/products/Hive/doc/JDBC_InstallGuide/content/jdbc/hi/authenticating/kerberos.htm).

Comment: I mainly gathered information from docs inside the downloadable content mentioned in step 1. Rest is from my experience. I'm using this technique almost always to connect through R. Let me know if I can help you in further details.